# Installed 17.10 on Acer Predator G3-710, but only boots into windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

In the BIOS I set:

```
Boot Options->Launch CSM->Always
            -> Boot Menu->Enabled
```

Also disabled Secure boot.

I then installed 17.10 from DVD and that seemed to go find (chose option to install next to Windows). Restarted after install and there's no option anywhere to boot into Ubuntu, it automatically boots into Windows 10.

Comment: I see you found a solution, but I want to point out that the source of your problem was that you enabled the Compatibility Support Module (CSM). Many people do this because they follow old and *bad* advice. In the vast majority of cases, the CSM should *not* be enabled. See [my page on the CSM](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for all the gory details.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to get it working after following some of the advice here:
https://forum.level1techs.com/t/unable-to-load-grub-bootloader-on-uefi-acer-predator-17/111233/12

Specifically, I booted with Ubuntu 17.10 on a USB stick and then installed boot-repair as they suggested and ran it as suggested. Also disabled CSM (CSM -> Never).

Answer (score 1):

I know I am quite late to the party on this one

I have a similar Acer Predator (17 - G9-793), and I can boot Ubuntu from the second SSD (two come in the laptop, set to use RAID0).
I have spent about 2 days straight getting this to work, so I hope this helps someone out there!

Part of the issue is that the BIOS does not allow you to boot from an alternative disk it seems.. no matter where I put Ubuntu, only the first HDD seemed to have a recognizable OS on it.

- boot-repair couldn't help
- SuperGrubDisk couldn't help

---

So quite a weird issue! Not sure what they have done to this BIOS to make it so. Here is how I got Ubuntu to work from the second SSD.

1. First install Ubuntu 16.04 with UEFI ENABLED
2. Then restart and SET the supervisor/user password in the BIOS
3. Once the passwords are set, "Secure Boot Mode:" settings becomes accessible under the "Security" tab in this BIOS
4. Choose "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing"

   - Select the HDD you installed Ubuntu on
   - Following the prompts for me here..
   - [HDD1] > [EFI] > [ubuntu] > [shimx64.efi]
   - Give it a nice name (I used **ubuntu**)
5. Save your changes in the BIOS
6. When you reboot, you should be able to boot from the UEFI installed ubuntu

I am aiming for a Win7/Ubuntu16 boot on this machine, with each OS getting one of the included SSDs. Will update if I can get that working.

---

If anyone is trying to create a Win7 USB drive with UEFI from Ubuntu, this might help:

- Read this: https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/
- Use two guides to make a UEFI Win7 disk from Ubuntu:

  - http://encoded.eternicode.com/creating-a-uefi-bootable-win7-usb-stick-from-linux
  - **AND STEP 11 HERE:** https://www.eightforums.com/threads/uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-in-windows.15458/

That being said, my install kept freezing during the windows logo animation, or it would repeat forever. So I am now trying to install Win7 legacy, then convert the disk to GPT using this guide: https://www.disk-partition.com/gpt-mbr/change-legacy-to-uefi-4348i.html

**Update:** In case anyone is struggling with Win7 stuck on a loading screen, it can be helped by changing your SATA controller config between AHCI/IDE and so on. Sometimes "compatibility mode" might help too. *Unfortunately on my laptop, none of those are available*, but I am happily running Ubuntu/Win10 dual boot now using both of the original RAID SSDs